# Hanging on startup

Tags: boot, asus, reinstall

I installed a copy of Ubuntu and when it restarted from installation, it was successful and fast. I reinstalled another copy of the OS, it won't get to the desktop itself and when I turn on my netbook, it says something like `(3 of 3) a start job is.....` it does this for a long time then, it shows up something like `[FAILED]......` It never stops doing this.

My netbook specs are:

```
ASUS Eee Pc X101CH
1 GB of RAM, 
320 GB of Storage 
Intel Atom Cedar Trail processor
```

Comment: The picture doesn't seem to show up, but it says something like (3 of 3) a start job is..... but it took so long then after sometime, it shows up something like [FAILED]...... And it never stops.. thanks

Comment: If you can give us an idea of what the start job is, we can help diagnose exactly what is causing the boot process to be blocked. Mail agents (postfix, sendmail, dovecot) are notorious for having long start jobs if DNS isn't reliable or unavailable.

Comment: Please include what version of Ubuntu you are installing, (14.04, 16.04, Lubuntu, etc)

Comment: Nevermind, I already fixed it. It turns out to be the installation process. BTW, it's a Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS!